# Formula for $\cos((2n+1)x)$ as polynomial of $\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking for a formula of $\cos((2n+1)x)$ that is polynomial of $\cos(x)$.
For example, $$\cos3\alpha=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha$$ Is it known for any $n$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: @HansLundmark Beat me to it ...

Comment: @HansLundmark great, thanks a lot

Comment: @HansLundmark Could you please convert your comment into an answer so this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" queue?

Comment: @RobertHoward: OK, done.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are the [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition), usually denoted $T_n(x)$.